# How to do blur multiple images in a column?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have tried the code from this https://medium.com/fluttervn/how-to-make-blur-effect-in-flutter-using-backdropfilter-imagefilter-559ffd8ab73. However its not having the effect I wanted.

```
children: <Widget>[
Card(
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/image1.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 250,
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 1.0, sigmaY: 1.0),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Image 1'),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
  Card(...),
  Card(...),
],
```

I have tried wrapping each individual card into a container but the previous cards keep getting blurred even the text. I only want the images of each individual card to be blurred while the text remains clear.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't test it but try to use instead of Image.asset the Container widget . As the example:

```
Container(
  width:x,
  height:y,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
     image: DecorationImage(
       image: AssetImage('assets/image1.jpg'),
       fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
  child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 1.0, sigmaY: 1.0),
                child: Container(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
  ),
),
```

Since every card is the same you can create a class as a constructor and u will just add `CardTemplate('text 1', 'assets/image1.jpg'),` when u need a card:

```
class CardTemplate extends StatelessWidget{



 String image;
 String text;
   
 CardTemplate(this.text,this.image);
 
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Card(
  child:Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Container(
           width: double.infinity,
          height: 250,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(this.image),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 1.0, sigmaY: 1.0),
                child: Container(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ),
      
    Center(
      child: Text(this.text),
     )
    ],
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

**Note I haven't tested the code so there will be maybe some syntax or typo errors**

Comment: I tried this but it only works for a single container. If there is more than 1 container, only the last container displays the desired effect while the blur effect becomes more for each container

Comment: Is a every card the same and the only thing that changes is the content or is every card unique?

Comment: every card is the same. only the content changes